# Semaphore wait within mutex lock

Tags: c, linux, algorithm, linux-kernel, operating-system

Can I call `semaphore.wait()` within mutex_lock if in the path somehow it can be guaranteed that resource protected by the semaphore is available?

I.e. I want to do something like following:

```
void some_function {

    mutex_lock()
    // Do something
    if (certain_conditions == TRUE) {
        semaphore_wait()   // Guaranteed that resource is available.
                           // Can not get blocked for sure.
    } 
    // Do some more things
    mutex_unlock()

}
```

Comment: Pedantic, but `if (certain_conditions = TRUE)` is not what you want (use `==`): please post acutal code not "something-like" code.

Comment: Can I do X if I can guarantee X will work? No, because somebody on StackOverflow says you're forbidden. :D JK. I think the answer's obvious, but if I were you I'd use the trywait variant (I think all reasonable semaphore implementation should have those) and `assert()` success.

Comment: If what you claim really is true, is the mysterious missing puzzle piece  that a way it can *not* be guaranteed to work is by releasing that mutex prior to the wait, someone else acquiring it, and thereafter breaking the warrant that the upcoming wait on this thread "can not get blocked for sure" ? Honestly, it sounds like you have a design hurdle, but with so little to go on that's just speculation.

Comment: If you can guarantee that the resource protected by the semaphore is always available, then why use a semaphore to protect it?

Comment: @Jim: It isn't always avaiable. Its only available hn certain conditions are true. My basic question is can one call semaphore wait frm within mutex_lock?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Edited and made the correction. My basic question is can one call wait from within mutex_lock. Actual code is yet to be developed and I'm writing an algo as part of design. Above code is what I intend to do.

Comment: Well, sure. It *can* be done. The worst that can happen is that the call will block, thus leaving the mutex acquired for an extended period. Which, granted, could lead to deadlock if for some unexpected reason the resource isn't available. But there's no language or runtime reason you can't call a sem_wait while you have a mutex.

Comment: Is this the code for run in *Linux kernel*? If so, drop `operating-system` tag - it is for questions about OS *in general*.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the answer to your question is:
**Yes. You can call a "wait" primitive on a semaphore within a Mutex lock context**.

Actually, that is something that is constantly done. Think of, for example, implementation of Message Queue IPC services with Counting Semaphores: you need to lock the Mutex protecting the queue before calling your "wait" primitive on the Counting Semaphore.

Thinking of POSIX, if you have to implement a Mailbox (typical Producer/Consumer example), you can safely and easily do it with Mutex and Condition Variables (which would be used as your Semaphores). What you want to do is nothing strange as long as you're in control of the situation.

Comment: 'you need to lock the Mutex protecting the queue before calling your "wait" primitive' - why is that?  If the mutex is locked, nothing else can push anything onto the queue.  It's normal to wait on the semaphore and then lock the mutex to access the queue.